# How do I give users the ability to make their private playlist?

Tags: python, html, django, web, playlist

I am creating a song website where users can view songs and add them to their playlist.
So I created almost every functionality of the website (songs,albums,artists) except User and Playlist. I know that we can create users account management system by two ways:

> 1) By using django's own user system
>
> 2) By creating our own custom UserProfile

I created the user profile system using Django's own user system. Users can register & login to my page.

Now I want to add the functionality of playlist to my website. After users are logged in, they could create their own private playlist  and add as much as songs to their playlist.

How can  I add this functionality of playlist? Im looking forward to your precious help.

```
#Models.py
class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    audio_file = models.FileField(default='', upload_to='song')
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    song_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)


    @property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.audio_file.path)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

Comment: Sounds like Playlist should be another Django app, and be owned by a particular user. The playlist may have a setting as to whether it's public or private. A playlist (I would think) would be nothing more than an ordered list of songs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need Playlist model, that could look like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class Playlist(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField("YourSongModel")
```

Comment: I added that and for testing purposes I omitted the owner object. 
My code:
`songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)`
how can I add songs from my Song model to songs?(im a newbie to django)